# Operações com quantidades de tempo e conversão entre unidades de tempo

Tags: c#

Existe alguma biblioteca especializada na manipulação de quantidades e unidades de tempo?
Que permita a conversão de/em milissegundos, segundos, minutos e operações de soma e subtração de quantidades de tempo.

Nativo no `c#` não encontrei nada que não exija muito esforço e cálculos de conversão.

Ou se existe nativamente como poderia obter o total de horas somando duas quantidades de tempo, como por exemplo:

03:20 + 03:50 = ?

Existe uma forma de fazer isso sem ter que destrinçar as horas e os minutos, fazendo validações para quando os minutos passarem de 59 se tornar uma hora a mais?

Comment: Sim, existe a FCL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)

Comment: Me da um exemplo de como eu efetuo a soma de horas com a FCL por favor. por exemplo somar `00:59 + 00:40`

Comment: Horas não podem ser somadas, isto não faz sentido, horas são pontos no tempo.

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio Não sei se entendi bem, mas seria algo [parecido com isso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g2C6Md)?

Comment: @Randrade é exatamente isso, muito obrigado, pode por como resposta, e se possível dar uma explicação para nosso amigo de como é possível somar "dois pontos no tempo"

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio Sua pergunta está fechada no momento, não sendo possível responder. Você pode [edit] a pergunta explicando melhor para ela ser reaberta. Seria útil você adicionar uma pergunta mais clara de exemplo, como "Como obter o total de horas somando duas horas, como por exemplo:`03:20` + `03:50`? Acho que assim ela ficaria mais clara e poderia ser reaberta.

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio Veja se este exemplo te ajuda: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YQkmqF

Comment: Você pediu a biblioteca e eu mostrei, se não queria saber isso, não perguntasse. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx Este é o objeto que armazena horários. Veja os métodos de soma e procure um que soma dois horários. Não tem. Você acha que a Microsoft esqueceu de pôr? Ela não colocou porque isto não faz sentido. Mostra pra mim uma operação onde precisa somar um ponto de entrada e um de saída e qual o resultado esperado. Isto não existe.

Comment: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time, http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time (tem mais de 100 coisas que a maioria das pessoas pensam que sabem sobre o assunto e não sabem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time Se melhorar sua pergunta como todos indicaram ela poderá ser reaberta, só reclamando não é possível. Informe o que realmente deseja, somar duas horas não é possível.

Comment: O que o @bigown disse sobre não ser possível "somar horas" faz sentido, se você lembrar de que horas não são valores numéricos inteiros, você não aplica operações aritméticas diretamente sobre horas. Você precisa converter para chegar em algo como "soma de horas". Talvez a melhor maneira de fazer isso de forma simples, seja adotar o mesmo padrão usado no Unix: converta as horas em segundos, faça as operações (soma, subtração, etc...) com os segundos e depois converta-os de volta. Dessa forma você assegura o resultado e não é difícil implementar. (Algo simples, claro.)

Comment: Blz. obrigado..

Comment: Essa pergunta [está sendo debatida no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6064/20615)

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio Se a edição que fiz não corresponder ao que pretendia perguntar, por favor reverta-a ou diga que eu faço.

Comment: Ao meu ver ficou bem mais coerente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Você pode somar as horas normalmente em C#. Para isso, basta garantir que a hora seja um [intervalo de tempo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx).

Você consegue realizar operações, sem problemas, com formatos do tipo [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) e [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) (esse para datas, juntamente com os horários).

Para somar dois horários, ou mais, basta somar normalmente. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var time = new TimeSpan(3, 20, 0);
var time2 = new TimeSpan(3, 50, 0);

var total = time + time2;
Console.WriteLine(total);
//Resultado: 07:10:00
```

[Exemplo no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AFIB4T)

Vale ressaltar que você possui diversos métodos para [utilizar com o TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3). Com eles, você obterá resultados mais precisos.

Um exemplo é se você somar valores que ultrapassem 24 horas. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var time = new TimeSpan(20, 20, 0);
var time2 = new TimeSpan(13, 50, 0);

var total = time.Add(time2);
Console.WriteLine(total.TotalHours);
//Resultado: 34.1666666666667
```

[Exemplo no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FxYoKz)

Veja a imagem abaixo para entender melhor os valores que você possui sem ser necessário "realizar validações" (como você disse em sua pergunta):

[image: Print]

Caso queira ver mais formas de realizar isso, veja mais alguns exemplos [no nosso irmão mais velho.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510778/4843158)

Comment: Excelente resposta obrigado.

Comment: Decidi não negativar ainda, mas a primeira frase já está errada. Os códigos apresentados não somam horas. A pergunta até agora não diz o que realmente quer somar. Se é horas, não dá e esta resposta está errada. Ensina errado. Agora se a pergunta for formulada com as informações necessárias para saber o que o AP deseja, aí pode até ser que ela esteja quase toda certa. Claro que ele aceitando pode parecer que era isso. Mas não temos como saber, porque existe outra resposta possível bem diferente desta dependendo do que é a pergunta de fato. Ele pode ter ficado contente e aprendido errado.

Comment: @bigown Você participou dos comentários (foi inclusive o primeiro). Tenho certeza que que com eles você conseguiu entender realmente o que o AP quer. Se está encomodado por eu ter utilizado o termo "horas", eu adicionei uma referência ao "intervalo de tempo", [que é utilizado pela MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Agora, sobre estar errado, seria interessante você mostrar o motivo.+

Comment: [Nos links em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas/210561?noredirect=1#comment430487_210468) não falam isso e sim muitas falácias sobre o tempo. Agora, se deseja negativar ou não, eu já não posso, e nem quero, fazer nada. Tenho que certeza que a resposta ajudou o AP e que agora ele saberá [somar uma jornada de trabalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas/210561?noredirect=1#comment430352_210468) se necessário.

Comment: Quando eu tiver tempo farei uma canônica sobre assunto porque quase ninguém entende sobre o assunto. E a pergunta não diz o que deseja, várias respostas divergentes podem ser postadas. Na forma atual não dá para responder.

Comment: Um detalhe extra para a resposta que pode ser interessante seria isto `TimeSpan parsed = TimeSpan.Parse("23:30");` ou `DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse("23:30");`

Answer (score 6):

É muito tranquilo manipular datas e horas se os mesmos estiverem em formato DateTime

```
//Cria uma nova data 09:00:00 06/06/2017
DateTime teste = new DateTime(2017, 6, 6, 9, 0, 0);
//Cria uma nova data 12:00:00 06/06/2017
DateTime teste2 = new DateTime(2017, 6, 6, 12, 0, 0);

//Adiciona uma hora, o resultado será 10:00:00 06/06/2017
teste.AddHours(1);
//Adiciona 30 minutos, o resultado será 09:30:00 06/06/2017
teste.AddMinutes(30)
//Soma a segunda data a primeira, o resultado será 21:00:00 06/06/2017
teste.Add(teste2.TimeOfDay());
```

Comment: Isto não está somando horas na forma como o AP descreveu. Até está somando de uma forma que obviamente funciona, mas é um horário com uma quantidade de horas, são conceitos distintos.

Comment: A ideia era demonstrar os métodos de manipulação da classe DateTime, e eu realmente esqueci de colocar o mais importante para o caso dele

Comment: Cara obrigado pela resposta, eu aceitei a do Randrade pois no caso dele, ele me oferece uma opção onde eu vou acumulando as horas e não apenas navegando no tempo, e eu precisava exatamente disso uma forma de somar e acumular o tempo. (horas:minutos)